# Sporadic value updates in html

Tags: angularjs, html, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have an AngularJs decorator directive that adds functionality to an html5 video player.  I am trying to get the speed (playbackRate) to display in html when the speed is increased using the (l/r) arrow keys and the current speed, volume and paused values when the player loads.  The events to do these operations fire and write the correct values to the console, but the html isn't updated.

Here's the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Decorators</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../js/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

    <script src="../js/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body ng-controller="mainCtrl" class="container" style="padding-top: 30px;">
    <video id="vid"
           keyboard-support
           event-load="handleLoad(volume, paused, speed)"
           event-pause="handlePause(isPaused)"
           event-volume="handleVolume(newVolume)"
           event-speed="handleSpeed(newSpeed)"
           controls preload="none"
           poster="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/poster.png">
      <source src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
      <source src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.webm5" type="video/webm"></source>
      <source src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.ogv" type="video/ogg"></source>
    </video>

    <div>
      Volume: {{theVolume | number:2}} <br/>
      Paused: {{(isPaused) ? 'yes' : 'no'}} <br/>
      Speed: {{thePlaybackSpeed | number:2}}
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Here's the script:

```
angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app').controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope) {

  $scope.handleLoad = function (vol, paused, speed) {

    console.log('in handle load - v:' + vol + ' p:' + paused + ' s:' + speed);

    $scope.theVolume = vol;
    $scope.isPaused = paused;
    $scope.thePlaybackSpeed = speed;
  };

  $scope.handlePause = function (b) {
    $scope.isPaused = b;
  };

  $scope.handleVolume = function (v) {
    $scope.theVolume = v;
  };

  $scope.handleSpeed = function (s) {
    console.log('current reading: ', $scope.playbackSpeed);
    console.log('new speed:', s);

    $scope.thePlaybackSpeed = s;
  }

});

angular.module('app').directive('eventPause', function ($parse) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
      var fn = $parse(attrs['eventPause']);   // get reference to function
      el.on('pause', function (event) {
        scope.$apply(function () {
          fn(scope, {isPaused: el[0].paused});
        })
      });

      el.on('play', function (event) {
        scope.$apply(function () {
          fn(scope, {isPaused: el[0].paused});
        })
      });
    }
  }
});

angular.module('app').directive('eventVolume', function ($parse) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
      var fn = $parse(attrs['eventVolume']);   // get reference to function
      el.on('volumechange', function (event) {
        scope.$apply(function () {
          fn(scope, {newVolume: el[0].volume});
        })
      })
    }
  }
});

angular.module('app').directive('eventSpeed', function ($parse) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, el, attrs, ctrl) {
      var fn = $parse(attrs['eventSpeed']);
      el.on('ratechange', function () {
        fn(scope, {newSpeed: el[0].playbackRate})
      })
    }
  }
});

angular.module('app').directive('eventLoad', function ($parse) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, el, attrs, ctrl) {
      var fn = $parse(attrs['eventLoad']);
      var player = el[0];
      el.on('loadstart', function () {
        console.log('in event-load');
        fn(scope, {volume: player.volume, paused: player.paused, speed: player.playbackRate})
      })
    }
  }
});

angular.module('app').directive('keyboardSupport', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, el, attrs) {

      var vidEl = el[0];

      $('body').on('keydown', function (evt) {

        console.log(evt.keyCode);

        switch (evt.keyCode) {
          case 32:    // spacebar
            pausePlay(vidEl);
            break;
          case 38:    // up arrow
            increaseVolume(vidEl);
            break;
          case 40:    // down arrow
            decreaseVolume(vidEl);
            break;
          case 39:    // right arrow key
            increasePlaybackSpeed(vidEl);
            break;
          case 37:    // left arrow key
            decreasePlaybackSpeed(vidEl);
            break;
        }
      });

      // pause/play
      function pausePlay(player) {
        if (player.paused) {
          player.play();
        } else {
          player.pause();
        }
      }

      function increaseVolume(player) {
        if (player.volume < 1) {
          player.volume += 0.1;
        }
      }

      function decreaseVolume(player) {
        if (player.volume > 0.1) {
          player.volume -= 0.1;
        }
      }

      function increasePlaybackSpeed(player) {
        if (player.playbackRate < 2) {
          player.playbackRate += 0.5;
        }
      }

      function decreasePlaybackSpeed(player) {
        if (player.playbackRate > -2) {
          player.playbackRate -= 0.5;
        }
      }

    }
  }
});
```

Here's a plnk to see issues:
http://plnkr.co/edit/odgoHiwHHEwjdKJn9agc